# How do I hook these js methods/functions with Frida?

Tags: frida, api-reversing

I want to hook these methods for the purpose to log the string variables (str) just before they are encrypted by a function (encr). I'm showing only the relevant parts for simplicity.

1-

```
 protected static String m1a(String str, String str2, String str3) {
 ...
 String str5 = ("dev=" + URLEncoder.encode(encr.mc(C20.f50))
 ...
```

2-

```
public final class a1c {
 
    public static String ma(String str) {
        return encr.m6b(str);
    }

}
```

3-

```
private void me(String str, String str2) {
        md(encr.m6a(str.substring(4)), str2);
    }
```

Comment: Please the title is not the first line of the question. BTW: "JS" means JavaScript but the posted code is Java not JavaScript which is a major difference. Please edit your question and write a full question including more details about what you want to hook, a J2SE application, and Android app? Also Stackexchange is a not a script writing service, what have you tried, ho far did you got? If you are unsure how to hook a method, use Jadx-Gui, select the method and let it generate the frida code snippet for you and place it in your Frida script.